# Break element onto new line when run out of space / upon window resize?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 6 boxes in a parent div like so:

```
- - - - - Parent Div - - - - -


   div div div div div div 


- - - - - Parent Div - - - - -
```

They are being spaced out using display flex.

However, upon window resize, i would like them to collapse to  3 x 3 and then 2 x 2. Ending up with:

```
- - - - - Parent Div - - - - -

           Div Div
           Div Div
           Div Div
```

Here's what i've tried but can't seem to get it to work. I still end up with 6 squished together in 1 row.

```
CSS:
.premium_listing_container {
  width: 990px;
    height:auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
     display: flex; 
justify-content: space-between;
flex-wrap: wrap;

}

.premium_component {
width:145.5px;
padding:0.4em;
 vertical-align: top;   
border:1px solid #878787;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
cursor: pointer;
margin-bottom:20px;

}
```

Please can someone show me where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need Media Queries. Flexbox won't do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I managed to do what I needed to do without the use of media queries. By utilising the inline-block display attribute.

I will hold off accepting my answer just yet to allow others to contribute a (better) answer - just incase there is one.

```
.premium_listing_container {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
 display: flex; 
justify-content: space-between;
flex-wrap: wrap;

}

.premium_component {
width:145.5px;
padding:0.4em;
 vertical-align: top;   
border:1px solid #878787;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
cursor: pointer;
margin-bottom:20px;
display: inline-block;

}
```